# Is the second completeness axiom for V really needed for Ackermann set theory to interpret ZF?

Tags: logic, set-theory, alternative-set-theories

If from the axioms of [Ackermann set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory) we remove the second completeness axiom for $V$, and replace it with an axiom of power sets in $V$, that is:

For every element $x$ of $V$: the class of all elements of $V$ that are subclasses of $x$, is an element of $V$.

Formally this is:

$\forall x \in V \ \forall y \ [\forall z (z \in y \leftrightarrow z \subseteq x \wedge z \in V) \to y \in V]$

where: $z \subseteq x \iff \forall m \in z (m \in x)$

Note: the second completeness axiom for $V$ is the axiom:

$\forall x \in V  \ \forall y \ (y \subseteq x \to y \in V)$

> Question: Is the resulting theory still capable of interpreting ZF?

Comment: This property is sometimes referred to as "supertransitive". Namely, $X$ is supertransitive if whenever $x\in X$ and $y\subseteq x$, then $y\in X$.

Comment: I think your definition of "supertransitive" is missing the condition that $X$ must be transitive.